# Changing a zone name with PDNS v1 API

Tags: powerdns

I have PowerDNS Authoritative Server 4.1.0-rc1 set up on server. I'm trying to change a zone domain name.

```
curl -X PUT \
  http://<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>/api/v1/servers/localhost/zones/<MY_DOMAIN>. \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-api-key: <MY_KEY>' \
  -d '{
      "kind": "Master",
      "name": "<NEW_NAME>."
  }'
```

A kind is being changed to Master, however name stays the same.

A document at https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/http-api/endpoint-zones.html says

> PUT /api/v1/servers/:server_id/zones/:zone_id Modifies basic zone data
>   (metadata).
>
> Changing name renames the zone, as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have contacted Pdns team and it looks like they do not support updating name and are going to remove it from 4.1 documentation.